# Firebase Database Child Values Showing null

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

When i upload my Post object with an array of image URLs to Firebase Database, some of the child values are showing empty. I have also tried uploading the Post Object without array that contains image urls and everything worked just fine. I think the array's causing child values to show empty. But i couldn't find a way to solve this problem. Any idea on this issue?

[Database nodes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6oT4c.jpg)

JSON file

```
{
  "post_images" : {
    "-MKRuWXlc_C9_XTlHbpC" : {
      "firstItem" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/sattimgitti-c6e5d.appspot.com/o/posts%2Fusers%2FF81LLbqVlpY75m1puEThf5yTXAE2%2F-MKRuWXlc_C9_XTlHbpC%2Fpost_image%2FImagesimage%3A15387?alt=media&token=5ea88271-524f-4cff-b900-c2555b7bcffd",
      "postImages" : [ "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/sattimgitti-c6e5d.appspot.com/o/posts%2Fusers%2FF81LLbqVlpY75m1puEThf5yTXAE2%2F-MKRuWXlc_C9_XTlHbpC%2Fpost_image%2FImagesimage%3A15387?alt=media&token=5ea88271-524f-4cff-b900-c2555b7bcffd", "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/sattimgitti-c6e5d.appspot.com/o/posts%2Fusers%2FF81LLbqVlpY75m1puEThf5yTXAE2%2F-MKRuWXlc_C9_XTlHbpC%2Fpost_image%2FImagesimage%3A15389?alt=media&token=b831db94-4633-44f5-aae7-89fa800e6f8b", "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/sattimgitti-c6e5d.appspot.com/o/posts%2Fusers%2FF81LLbqVlpY75m1puEThf5yTXAE2%2F-MKRuWXlc_C9_XTlHbpC%2Fpost_image%2FImagesimage%3A15382?alt=media&token=4c8ea5f3-2bb2-4830-a245-7141154160cf" ]
    },
    "-MKRw2rzTdpsn1SZSyDp" : {
      "firstItem" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/sattimgitti-c6e5d.appspot.com/o/posts%2Fusers%2FF81LLbqVlpY75m1puEThf5yTXAE2%2F-MKRw2rzTdpsn1SZSyDp%2Fpost_image%2FImagesimage%3A15355?alt=media&token=df288b1d-724c-486b-b037-7fc93cdd05a1",
      "postImages" : [ "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/sattimgitti-c6e5d.appspot.com/o/posts%2Fusers%2FF81LLbqVlpY75m1puEThf5yTXAE2%2F-MKRw2rzTdpsn1SZSyDp%2Fpost_image%2FImagesimage%3A15355?alt=media&token=df288b1d-724c-486b-b037-7fc93cdd05a1", "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/sattimgitti-c6e5d.appspot.com/o/posts%2Fusers%2FF81LLbqVlpY75m1puEThf5yTXAE2%2F-MKRw2rzTdpsn1SZSyDp%2Fpost_image%2FImagesimage%3A15354?alt=media&token=c2059e03-62f5-464d-9708-79f95c43bff1", "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/sattimgitti-c6e5d.appspot.com/o/posts%2Fusers%2FF81LLbqVlpY75m1puEThf5yTXAE2%2F-MKRw2rzTdpsn1SZSyDp%2Fpost_image%2FImagesimage%3A15257?alt=media&token=d1eec3a8-6517-455c-8140-14fe731a6764", "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/sattimgitti-c6e5d.appspot.com/o/posts%2Fusers%2FF81LLbqVlpY75m1puEThf5yTXAE2%2F-MKRw2rzTdpsn1SZSyDp%2Fpost_image%2FImagesimage%3A15244?alt=media&token=18496985-1991-44a7-88b7-08125cf788ee" ]
    },
    "posts" : {
      "-MKS3CIuGKMPwoPdqeev" : {
        "city" : "",
        "description" : "",
        "image" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/sattimgitti-c6e5d.appspot.com/o/posts%2Fusers%2FF81LLbqVlpY75m1puEThf5yTXAE2%2F-MKS3CIuGKMPwoPdqeev%2Fpost_image%2FImagesimage%3A15384?alt=media&token=5a7ab620-2bfc-4dd8-9a18-f395917b72bb",
        "post_id" : "-MKS3CIuGKMPwoPdqeev",
        "price" : "",
        "title" : "",
        "user_id" : "F81LLbqVlpY75m1puEThf5yTXAE2"
      },
      "-MKSClUrxJKFTBP_FhvR" : {
        "city" : "",
        "description" : "",
        "postImages" : [ "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/sattimgitti-c6e5d.appspot.com/o/posts%2Fusers%2FF81LLbqVlpY75m1puEThf5yTXAE2%2F-MKSClUrxJKFTBP_FhvR%2Fpost_image%2FImagesimage%3A15387?alt=media&token=9e410ab2-740a-48a1-9b51-51fb2011aa53", "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/sattimgitti-c6e5d.appspot.com/o/posts%2Fusers%2FF81LLbqVlpY75m1puEThf5yTXAE2%2F-MKSClUrxJKFTBP_FhvR%2Fpost_image%2FImagesimage%3A15382?alt=media&token=ba1302e0-9bc6-4c06-9352-81ec995a5246", "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/sattimgitti-c6e5d.appspot.com/o/posts%2Fusers%2FF81LLbqVlpY75m1puEThf5yTXAE2%2F-MKSClUrxJKFTBP_FhvR%2Fpost_image%2FImagesimage%3A15383?alt=media&token=cc9c664c-a2dd-4e0d-9d1d-207252742e83", "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/sattimgitti-c6e5d.appspot.com/o/posts%2Fusers%2FF81LLbqVlpY75m1puEThf5yTXAE2%2F-MKSClUrxJKFTBP_FhvR%2Fpost_image%2FImagesimage%3A15384?alt=media&token=90c4db1c-66d7-4aa4-932f-ab585d0a93ba" ],
        "post_id" : "-MKSClUrxJKFTBP_FhvR",
        "price" : "",
        "title" : "",
        "user_id" : "F81LLbqVlpY75m1puEThf5yTXAE2"
      }
    }
}
```

Post Object

```
public class Post  {
    private String post_id;
    private String user_id;
    private String  image;
    private String title;
    private String description;
    private String price;
    private String city;
    private ArrayList<String> postImages;

    public Post(String post_id, String user_id, String  image, String title, String description, String price, String city, ArrayList<String> postImages) {
        this.post_id = post_id;
        this.user_id = user_id;
        this.image = image;
        this.title = title;
        this.description = description;
        this.price = price;
        this.city = city;
        this.postImages = postImages;
    }

    public String getPost_id() {
        return post_id;
    }

    public void setPost_id(String post_id) {
        this.post_id = post_id;
    }

    public String getUser_id() {
        return user_id;
    }

    public void setUser_id(String user_id) {
        this.user_id = user_id;
    }

    public String  getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getPostImages(){
        return postImages;
    }

    public void setUrlArray(ArrayList<String> postImages){
        this.postImages = postImages;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(String price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }



    public Post(){

    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Post{" +
                "post_id='" + post_id + '\'' +
                ", user_id='" + user_id + '\'' +
                ", image='" + image + '\'' +
                ", title='" + title + '\'' +
                ", description='" + description + '\'' +
                ", price='" + price + '\'' +
                ", urlArray='" + postImages + '\'' +
                ", city='" + city + '\'' +
                '}';
    }


}
```

PostActivity.java (this method contains all the relevant pieces)

```
private void uploadPostwithImages(){


        postId = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().push().getKey();
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("post_images");
        final StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference()
                .child("posts/users/" + FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid() +
                        "/" + postId + "/post_image");

        int upload_count = 0;
        urlStrings = new ArrayList<>();
        for (upload_count = 0; upload_count < mArrayUri.size(); upload_count++) {

            IndividualImage = mArrayUri.get(upload_count);
            final StorageReference ImageName = storageReference.child("Images" + IndividualImage.getLastPathSegment());



            ImageName.putFile(IndividualImage).addOnSuccessListener(
                    new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                            Task<Uri> firebaseUri = taskSnapshot.getMetadata().getReference().getDownloadUrl();

                            firebaseUri.addOnSuccessListener(
                                    new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {

                                            urlStrings.add(String.valueOf(uri));

                                            Post post = new Post();

                                            if (urlStrings.size() == mArrayUri.size()){
                                                //storeLink(urlStrings);
                                                post.setUrlArray(urlStrings);
                                            }

                                            post.setCity(inputCity.getText().toString());
                                            post.setDescription(inputDesc.getText().toString());
                                            post.setPost_id(postId);
                                            post.setPrice(inputPrice.getText().toString());
                                            post.setTitle(inputTitle.getText().toString());
                                            post.setUser_id(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());
                                            reference.child(getString(R.string.node_posts))
                                                    .child(postId)
                                                    .setValue(post);

                                        }
                                    }
                            );
                        }
                    }
            );
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include: 1) the JSON that your code reads (as text, no screenshots please). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data). 2) the minimal code that is needed to reproduce the exact problem. If only some values are empty, we'll only want to see those values.

Comment: I guess the Url that i pass to putFile() causes this problem. I've tried another url without arrray and it worked. But i really should upload the object along with the array of images.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I don't want to duplicate the question but I'm still struggling with this issue.

Comment: You seem to have a hypothesis about the cause of the problem, so should validate that hypothesis. For example, if you put a breakpoint on the `reference.child(getString(R.string.node_posts))
                                                    .child(postId)
                                                    .setValue(post);` and run the code in a debugger, does it hit that line, and if so, are all the vallues what you expect them to be?

Comment: As far as i observe there's nothing wrong with the way object uploads. It seems like there's not a possible way for object to contain an array of image urls. If i switch the array with a single image url, everything's fine. I just don't understand why object cant be uploaded with an array.

Comment: I don't see what in the code you shared could be causing some of the properties to be empty. It sees unlikely that it's cause by the array of image URLs, but if you say it disappears when you disable that code, I'd recommend debugging that further. Sorry I can't say more.